# Get data from/to Android app every time data changes in web service data base

Tags: android, web-services, rest, dynamic

This question might have been answered previously but I could not find it. Apologies for that.

In my android application I have a List with orders data. 
I have my web service which can send the Orders data from the database.

I am familiar with the way where the Android app can request the web service for Orders data.

If my Orders data from the web service (database) changes every minute/seconds and I want update the List view instantaneously. Is Running an Async task every second to check with web service for new data a good way? I think this kills the battery life as the Async task runs every second.

Is there an alternative best way to do this.

Can web service constantly check its data base and send data to the android application if the data in the orders table changes.

I have heard about Firebase from Google not sure if that serves the purpose.

Could you advice me on whats the best way to get the data every minute or second from the database.

Comment: Firebase realtime databases are really good at this, and deal with everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) is what you want. It updates data in real-time.

Comment: I am pretty new to Firebase. so u mean I can host my webservices on it and use the Firebase database?

Comment: Yes. It provides all the web service backbone you need so you don't have to implement your own.